# tsdoc info lost after bind a methord to an object

Tags: typescript, tsdoc

I incidentally found:

```
/** foo is a method **/
let foo = ()=>{}
foo() // here tsdoc work fine if you hover the cursor on it
let obj={foo: foo}
obj.foo() // here tsdoc info is lost
```

If you visit the foo method via `obj.foo()`, the tsdoc info will lose. What's the cause of it?

Comment: This problem is not directly related to TypeScript. Additional hints based on the documentation of your methods are processed differently in different IDEs. What IDE are you using?

Comment: For example, in VSCode ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhAIDMHtvBLAzuAhuAtgUwC4AtoAm4YwAUADY5SzgC84AFAJS0B8A3gL6kzTPjBg4XJgBOmcNkQFoAY3AB3aKIDWUeADsJ8SOACe0AK7DoANzGSR4WYdGJl4aBoTYKVaACMAVrXa8AXNTQ3KSeXgB0vPyCwmISUjLymjAIyOTQiNhAA)) I receive hints.

Comment: @FlatGlobe, my apologies, I will close this quetion. Here's anothe question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75497659/typedoc-info-will-be-lost-after-exported-as-a-default